# jquery autocomplete the right way to bind it

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I have jquery code but gives a syntax error and I cannot figure it out. Would you please take a look at it.

I have the code working but I need to change the way I bind the event handler, and when I change it, it doesnt work.

this code works perfectly but I need to change it with the commented one

```
//$("#wrapper").on("autocomplete", "#update_speciality", function () { 
  $("#update_speciality").autocomplete({
            ...........
  });
```

There is something wrong with this code but canot figure it out. Would you please help?

```
  $("#wrapper").on("autocomplete", "#update_speciality", function () { 
            ...........
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $("#wrapper").on("keydown.autocomplete","#update_speciality",function(e){
    $(this).autocomplete({
      source : 'yoururl'
    });
  });
});
```

Also use proper ID naming so instead of update_speciality write **update-speciality** [ID and Class Name Delimiters](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=ID_and_Class_Name_Delimiters#ID_and_Class_Name_Delimiters) as recommended by [Google HTML/CSS Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml)

Comment: Perfect, it works... I have to wait 5 mins to mark it as answered

Answer (score 1):

The `autocomplete` is not a jQuery event, it is a jQuery UI widget http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/.  The `on` method supports event handling only.

Comment: what can I use besaide .on() ? I have a form which is supposed to be cleared and recreated dynamically to show to the user. But when I recreate it, event disapear

Comment: You cannot use event bubbling with autocomplete, you must call it each time you create a new element